¿Cómo puedo mejorar mi regex?
No puedo encontrar como ajustar mi regex, necesito capturar ciertos datos de unos usuarios después de escanear un pdf con python, para después pasarlos a un form. Pero el texto en que vienen los datos siempre varia mucho, errores de ortografía, caracteres random, etc. Es una locura lo mal que envían esos datos, quería saber como puedo hacer para mejorar el código o donde aprender para resolver esto.
Una de las soluciones que tuve fue escribir varios regex adaptando a lo que pasaba pero no siempre funciona abajo ejemplos. El código esta escrito en Python.
r'(ACORDADO CON)\s_+([\w\s]+)[\s_]*(CUIL|CUIT)\s*[(_]*([\d]+)[)_]*\s*MEDIANTE TRANSFERENCIA BANCARIA EN\s*\$?[\s_]*([\d.,]+)\s*-?\.?'
r'(ACORDADO CON\s*([A-Z\s,]+)\s*(CUIL|CUIT)\s*(\d+[\d\-]*)')
r'(ACORDADO CON)\s_*([\w\s]+)[\s_]*(CUI|CUIT|CUIL)\s*([\d]+)[)_]*\s*MEDIANTE TRANSFERENCIA BANCARIA EN\s*\$?[\s_]*([\d.,]+)\s*-?\.?'

Con este regex lo que hago es extraer el nombre pongamosle "Usuario", Documento y un monto de dinero acordado, ahora les paso a mostrar como vienen estos datos aveces.

ACORDADO CON Fulanito
ROLANDO - CUIL 20XXXXXXXX MEDIANTE
TRANSFERENCIA BANCARIA EN $1.400.000-


ACORDADO CON
_PAXXXXX LUXXXX ANDRES CUIL20XXXXXXXX MEDIANTE TRANSFERENCIA BANCARIA EN $362.500.-


ACORDADO CON- MENGANO _ROLANDO CUI20XXXXXX MEDIANTE TRANSFERENCIA BANCARIA EN.- $303.123,2-.-

Estos fueron unos ejemplos de tantos de como varia como viene escrita la información, aveces pueden venir con muchos mas errores y el algoritmo no los detecta y después tengo que pasarlos a mano.
El formato correcto de la extracción seria este eso implica ignorar todos los errores que tenga el texto:

MENGANITO TROLENCIO 20XXXXXX $50.0000


Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera medalla!

En mi modesta opinión, cuando se complica mucho el uso de regex, hay que olvidarse de ellos, creo que este es uno de esos casos, te dejo una alternativa, que (al menos en los ejemplos que diste) funciona bien.
cadenas = [
    "ACORDADO CON Fulanito ROLANDO - CUIL 20XXXXXXXX MEDIANTE TRANSFERENCIA BANCARIA EN $1.400.000-",
    "ACORDADO CON _PAXXXXX LUXXXX ANDRES CUIL20XXXXXXXX MEDIANTE TRANSFERENCIA BANCARIA EN $362.500.-",
    "ACORDADO CON- MENGANO _ROLANDO CUI20XXXXXX MEDIANTE TRANSFERENCIA BANCARIA EN.- $303.123,2-.-"
]

for cad in cadenas:
     # con "posCon", "posCuil" y "posPesos", ubicamos ountos claves de la cadena
     # que nos permiten alcanzar el resultado
    posCon = cad.find( "CON") + 3
    posCuil = cad.find( "CUIL")
     # en uno de los ejemplos, la cadena contiene "CUI" en lugar de "CUIL"
    if posCuil == -1:
        posCuil = cad.find( "CUI" )
    posPesos = cad.find( "$")
     # estos booleanos los usaremos para determinar en que etapa de la busqueda estamos
    buscaInicioNombre = True
    buscaFinNombre = False
    buscaInicioCuil = False
    buscaFinCuil = False
     # las variables que oportunamente instanciaremos con las posiciones de inicio
     # y fin, de las frases a devolver
    posIniNombre = 0
    posFinNombre = 0
    posIniCuil = 0
    posFinCuil = 0
    posFinPesos = 0
     # empezamos a recorrer la cadena, desde la posición final de "CON"
    for i in range( posCon, len ( cad ) ):
        letra = cad[ i ]
         # detrás del "CON", las letras que se encuentran antes de "CUIL", corresponden 
         # al nombre, sabemos que después de los espacios en blanco, empieza el nombre
         # cuando aparece una letra, guardamos su posicion y entramos a la segunda etapa
        if buscaInicioNombre:
            if letra.isalpha():
                posIniNombre = i
                buscaInicioNombre = False
                buscaFinNombre = True
         # camos modificando la posición final, con cada letra encontrada, esta etapa termina
         # cuando alcanzamos el valor de "posCuil"
        elif buscaFinNombre:
            if letra.isalpha():
                posFinNombre = i
            if i == posCuil -1:
                buscaFinNombre = False
                buscaInicioCuil = True
         # esperamos la aparición del "2", para determinar el inicio del  "Cuil", y 
         # determinamos su final, buscando el primer espacio vacio
        elif buscaInicioCuil:
            if i > posCuil:
                if letra == "2":
                    posIniCuil = i
                    posFinCuil = cad.find(  " ", i )
                    buscaInicioCuil = False 
         # tenemos la posición incial de valor numérico, y cuando aparezca un " " o un "-", 
         # tendremos el final
        else: 
            if i > posPesos:
                if letra != " " and letra != "-":
                    posFinPesos = i + 1
                else:
                    break

    print( cad[ posIniNombre: posFinNombre ] + " " 
         + cad[ posIniCuil: posFinCuil ] + " "
         + cad[ posPesos + 1: posFinPesos ])
    

Esto retorna:
Fulanito ROLAND 20XXXXXXXX 1.400.000  
PAXXXXX LUXXXX ANDRE 20XXXXXXXX 362.500.  
MENGANO _ROLAND 20XXXXXX 303.123,2  

=== Code Execution Successful ===

Probablemente, este no sea el código final que utilizarás, tal vez aparezcan otras variaciones que te obliguen a adaptarlo (o simplemente lo mejores), solo creo que es un buen punto de partida.
Ah, por cierto, Hola Draken, bienvenido, (aparte de saludarte como corresponde, verifico si el sistema borra el saludo estando este, colocado en el final... si, toy loco jaja).

Fuaa hermano muchas gracias, me funciono perfecto. 14/14 pruebas son las que tenia a mano, mi código con Regex solucionaba 8/14 en esta prueba, voy a seguir tu consejo para la próxima cuando se complique mucho con Regex lo mejor será sacar las cosas manualmente ajajaja y gracias por la bienvenida!!

Un placer haberte ayudado!!.

Podrías utilizar esta RegEx:
^ACORDADO CON[ _-]+(\w.+[^ -])[ -]+CUIL*[ ]*([0-9X]+) MEDIANTE TRANSFERENCIA BANCARIA EN[ .-]+(\$[0-9.,]+[0-9])[-.]+$

Ejemplo:
import re

regex = re.compile(r"^ACORDADO CON[ _-]+(\w.+[^ -])[ -]+CUIL*[ ]*([0-9X]+) MEDIANTE TRANSFERENCIA BANCARIA EN[ .-]+(\$[0-9.,]+[0-9])[-.]+$", re.IGNORECASE)

arr = [
    "ACORDADO CON Fulanito ROLANDO - CUIL 20XXXXXXXX MEDIANTE TRANSFERENCIA BANCARIA EN $1.400.000-",
    "ACORDADO CON _PAXXXXX LUXXXX ANDRES CUIL20XXXXXXXX MEDIANTE TRANSFERENCIA BANCARIA EN $362.500.-",
    "ACORDADO CON- MENGANO _ROLANDO CUI20XXXXXX MEDIANTE TRANSFERENCIA BANCARIA EN.- $303.123,2-.-"
]
for s in arr:
    print(regex.sub('\\1 \\2 \\3', s))

Resultado:
Fulanito ROLANDO 20XXXXXXXX $1.400.000
PAXXXXX LUXXXX ANDRES 20XXXXXXXX $362.500
MENGANO _ROLANDO 20XXXXXX $303.123,2

Demo
